# Convert multiple Word documents to HTML files using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I convert multiple MS Word documents in a certain folder to HTML using VBA?
I have used Powershell to do this but unfortunately the access is blocked to run the scripts.

Comment: Please take a moment to review the site's usage guidelines in the [help] for asking questions. This is much too broad - you're asking people to do all your work for you. Edit the question to include what you've tried (the Powershell script as a [mcve], for example and any attempt you've made to convert this to VBA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeDocsToTxtOrRTFOrHTML()
'with export to PDF in Word 2007
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim tFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim intPos As Integer
    Dim locFolder As String
    Dim fileType As String
    On Error Resume Next
    locFolder = InputBox("Enter the folder path to DOCs", "File Conversion", "C:\myDocs")
    Select Case Application.Version
        Case Is < 12
            Do
                fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change DOC to TXT, RTF, HTML", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
            Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML")
        Case Is >= 12
            Do
                fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change DOC to TXT, RTF, HTML or PDF(2007+ only)", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
            Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML" Or fileType = "PDF")
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder)
    Set tFolder = fs.CreateFolder(locFolder & "Converted")
    Set tFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder & "Converted")
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Dim d As Document
        Set d = Application.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)
        strDocName = ActiveDocument.Name
        intPos = InStrRev(strDocName, ".")
        strDocName = Left(strDocName, intPos - 1)
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory tFolder
        Select Case fileType
        Case Is = "TXT"
            strDocName = strDocName & ".txt"
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText
        Case Is = "RTF"
            strDocName = strDocName & ".rtf"
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF
        Case Is = "HTML"
            strDocName = strDocName & ".html"
            ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatFilteredHTML
        Case Is = "PDF"
            strDocName = strDocName & ".pdf"

            ' *** Word 2007 users - remove the apostrophe at the start of the next line ***
            'ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strDocName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
           
        End Select
        d.Close
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory oFolder
    Next oFile
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub ConvertDocs()
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim tFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim intPos As Integer
    Dim locFolder As String
    Dim fileType As String
    Dim office2007 As Boolean
    Dim lf As LinkFormat
    Dim oField As Field
    Dim oIShape As InlineShape
    Dim oShape As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    locFolder = InputBox("Enter the path to the folder with the documents to be converted", "File Conversion", "C:\myDocs")
    If Application.Version >= 12 Then
        office2007 = True
        Do
            fileType = UCase(InputBox("Enter one of the following formats (to convert to): TXT, RTF, HTML, DOC, DOCX or PDF", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
        Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML" Or fileType = "PDF" Or fileType = "DOC" Or fileType = "DOCX")
    Else
        office2007 = False
        Do
            fileType = UCase(InputBox("Enter one of the following formats (to convert to): TXT, RTF, HTML or DOC", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
        Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML" Or fileType = "DOC")
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder)
    Set tFolder = fs.CreateFolder(locFolder & "Converted")
    Set tFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder & "Converted")
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Dim d As Document
        Set d = Application.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)
        ' put the document into print view
        If fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "DOC" Or fileType = "DOCX" Then
            With ActiveWindow.View
                .ReadingLayout = False
                .Type = wdPrintView
            End With
        End If
        ' try to embed linked images from fields, shapes and inline shapes into the document
        ' (for some reason this does not work for all images in all HTML files I've tested)
        If Not fileType = "HTML" Then
            For Each oField In d.Fields
                Set lf = oField.LinkFormat
                If oField.Type = wdFieldIncludePicture And Not lf Is Nothing And Not lf.SavePictureWithDocument Then
                    lf.SavePictureWithDocument = True
                    Sleep (2000)
                    lf.BreakLink()
                    d.UndoClear()
                End If
            Next
            For Each oShape In d.Shapes
                Set lf = oShape.LinkFormat
                If Not lf Is Nothing And Not lf.SavePictureWithDocument Then
                    lf.SavePictureWithDocument = True
                    Sleep (2000)
                    lf.BreakLink()
                    d.UndoClear()
                End If
            Next
            For Each oIShape In d.InlineShapes
                Set lf = oIShape.LinkFormat
                If Not lf Is Nothing And Not lf.SavePictureWithDocument Then
                    lf.SavePictureWithDocument = True
                    Sleep (2000)
                    lf.BreakLink()
                    d.UndoClear()
                End If
            Next
        End If
        strDocName = d.Name
        intPos = InStrRev(strDocName, ".")
        strDocName = Left(strDocName, intPos - 1)
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory(tFolder)
        ' Check out these links for a comprehensive list of supported file formats and format constants:
        ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat.aspx
        ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238158.aspx
        ' (In the latter list you can see the values that the constants are associated with.
        '  Office 2003 only supported values up to wdFormatXML(=11). Values from wdFormatXMLDocument(=12)
        '  til wdFormatDocumentDefault(=16) were added in Office 2007, and wdFormatPDF(=17) and wdFormatXPS(=18)
        '  were added in Office 2007 SP2. Office 2010 added the various wdFormatFlatXML* formats and wdFormatOpenDocumentText.)
        If Not office2007 And fileType = "DOCX" Then
            fileType = "DOC"
        End If
        Select Case fileType
            Case Is = "TXT"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".txt"
                d.SaveAs(FileName := strDocName, FileFormat := wdFormatText)
            Case Is = "RTF"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".rtf"
                d.SaveAs(FileName := strDocName, FileFormat := wdFormatRTF)
            Case Is = "HTML"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".html"
                d.SaveAs(FileName := strDocName, FileFormat := wdFormatFilteredHTML)
            Case Is = "DOC"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".doc"
                d.SaveAs(FileName := strDocName, FileFormat := wdFormatDocument)
            Case Is = "DOCX"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".docx"
                ' *** Word 2007+ users - remove the apostrophe at the start of the next line ***
                'd.SaveAs(FileName := strDocName, FileFormat := wdFormatDocumentDefault)
            Case Is = "PDF"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".pdf"
                ' *** Word 2007 SP2+ users - remove the apostrophe at the start of the next line ***
                'd.ExportAsFixedFormat(OutputFileName := strDocName, ExportFormat := wdExportFormatPDF)
        End Select
        d.Close
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory(oFolder)
    Next oFile
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Also, see this...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vFQV6RtYMM

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Word VBA program to do this.  The program is open-source, under the MIT License.
The program is in a Word-doc on Github at:

https://github.com/jimyuill/word-web-nav/blob/main/tools/generate_word_html.docm

The Word-doc's text describes how to use the program.
The code is commented to explain how it works (alt+F11 opens the IDE).

The program optionally adds a table-of-contents to the beginning of the document.  That part of the code can be ignored, for the OP.

As mentioned by [@Cindy Meister](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592257/convert-multiple-word-documents-to-html-files-using-vba#comment99763980_56592257), the OP is "much too broad".  The program is too big to post all of the code here.  In summary:

**Prompt for input Word-docs:**

There is code to prompt the user for the Word-docs to be converted, from a particular directory. Most of that code is adapted from the example program here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.initialview

One of two APIs is used to get the list of Word-docs.  Each API presents a GUI for file-system browsing.

One API allows the user to select particular files in a directory.  The API is: Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog

The other API allows the user to just select a directory.  All Word-docs in it are converted.  The API is: Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msofiledialogtype

The program checks if there are two input Word-docs with the same root-name, and the extensions .doc, .docx, or .docm, e.g., "foo.doc" and "foo.docx". This isn't allowed for input Word-docs because, for each Word-doc, a Word HTML-file is created using the Word-doc's root-name: 
<root-name>.html

**Save each Word-doc in HTML format:**

Within the chosen directory, the program creates a subdirectory that will be used to hold the Word-docs' HTML files and directories.

The program loops to process each input Word-doc. Below are highlights of the code for each doc (some code is omitted). The code is based on the answer by [@ASH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56607409/15425447)

```
    ' Open the Word doc
    Set wordDocObj = Application.Documents.Open(fileObj.Path)

    ' Change the current directory to the output-directory
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory outputFolderObj        

    ' Save the Word-doc in the format "filtered" HTML
    fileBaseName = fileSystemObj.GetBaseName(fileName)
    outputFileName = fileBaseName & ".html"
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:=outputFileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatFilteredHTML

    ' Close the Word doc
    wordDocObj.Close

    ' Change the current directory to the input-directory
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory sourceFolderObj
```